# conditionally compounding an SQL query in Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have several of if-statements that build a query string and a set of arguments, like so:

```
search_string = ""
arguments = []

if params["this_data"] != nil
    search_string << " AND this_data = ?"
    arguments << params["this_data"]
end
if params["that_data"] != nil
    search_string << " AND that_data = ?"
    arguments << params["that_data"]
end
```

This goes on and on until the `search_string` is built. Now I'm trying to run the query, and am not having much success.  I am stuck on the following code, which is returning a syntax error:

```
Item.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM items WHERE thing IS NOT NULL ? ?", search_string, arguments])
```

I'm still plugging along at it, but so far, I'm not sure how I can compound this SQL string into something that returns a successful result.

Comment: I think the problem is with `? ?`. Maybe try `WHERE thing is not null AND ... ? AND ...?`

Comment: Not having much luck, still getting the exact same syntax error.

`SELECT * FROM items WHERE thing IS NOT NULL ' AND this_data = ?' AND '470'`

Part of the problem seems to be that it's putting quotes around my where clause.

Comment: Actually (and I do not recommend this) I think it should be `Item.where("thing IS NOT NULL #{search_string}",*arguments)`

Comment: That would work, except that I absolutely have to avoid using string interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options

```
scope = Item.where("thing IS NOT NULL") # rails 5 .where.not(thing: nil)
scope = scope.where(this_data: params["this_data"]) unless params["this_data"].nil?
scope = scope.where(that_data: params["that_data"]) unless params["that_data"].nil?
```

Or

```
search_keys = ["this_data","that_data"]
Item.where("thing IS NOT NULL").where(params.select {|k,v| search_keys.include?(k) && !v.nil? })
```

Both of these options will obtain the result you are looking for and will be concatenated with the joining "AND" with all the SQL parameter escaping that `ActiveRecord` provides

Comment: Nice!  I think something like your second solution will work best in my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AAAGH I figured it out.

I need to do this:

```
search_string = Item.where("thing IS NOT NULL")

if params["this_data"] != nil
    search_string = search_string.where("this_data = ?", params["this_data"])
end
if params["that_data"] != nil
    search_string = search_string.where("that_data = ?", params["that_data"])
end
```

etc...